# как сделать редирект на именованный маршрут передавая в него id динамически?

Tags: php, laravel

к примеру есть

```php
Route::get('/page/{id}', [PageController::class, 'page'])->name('getPage');
```

а в коде
**можно сделать так:**

```php
return redirect('/page/' . $page->id)
```

ну если поменяется вот это `'/page/{id}'` то придется менять везде

Comment: не отвечу вам за ларавель, но в нормальных маршрутизаторах кроме адреса есть ещё и имя. И перенаправления делают по ним. Должно получиться что-то вроде `makePage('route_name', ['id' => $page->id])`

Comment: Это есть в документации - [именованные роуты](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes)